# Node JS setup page throws blank page

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a node js server and client setup to use socket.io (Tutorial at [Daniel Nill](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/))

I've two files in the same directory `server.js` & `socket.html`.

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
console.log('Connection');

var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
console.log(path);

switch(path){
    case '/':
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write('hello world');
        break;
    case '/socket.html':

        console.log("Path: " + __dirname + path);

        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("Error 1: opps this doesn't exist - 404");

                console.log("With Error");
            }else{
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write(data, "utf8");

                console.log("Without Error");
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("Error 2: opps this doesn't exist - 404");
        break;
}
response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);
```

socket.html

```
<html>
  <head>This is the title</head>
  <body>This is our socket.html file</body>
</html>
```

The terminal shows this output

```
MacBook-Pro:nodejs ptamzz$ node server.js
Connection
/socket.html
Path: /Users/ptamzz/Documents/nodejs/socket.html
Without Error
```

But when I try to access `http://localhost:8001/socket.html`, the browser throws a blank page.

As per my understanding, am I not suppose to get the content of the HTML file `socket.html` as the `console.log("Without Error")` is shown up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because in case of `/socket.html` path you use asynchronous method (`fs.readFile`) with a callback which is being called **after** `response.end()` call. So you first end the response and then, say in 10ms when node completed reading a file, you call `response.write(data, "utf8");`.

To fix that put `response.end()` just after `response.write(data, "utf8");`

Comment: Thank you. It works. But does this mean I've to put `response.end();` after every `response.write();` in this instance?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's why many people prefer to use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) which makes programming on node easier and more enjoyable

Comment: To make my last comment a bit more clear: you have to write `response.end()` in the end of each scenario, but only **once** per scenario.